# Flaten array to 1D and assigning 'associative' keynames recursively

Tags: php, array

I would like to convert ($`data`):

```
Array
(
    [login] => Log in
    [logout] => Log out

    [label] => Array
        (
            [email] => test@test.com 
            [name] => Some name
        )

    [controllers] => Array
        (
            [page] => Array
                (
                    [title_new] => New page 
                    [title_edit] => Edit page
                    [submit_button] => Submit page
                )
        )
)
```

To (`$result`):

```
Array
(
    [login] => Log in
    [logout] => Log out
    [label[email]] => test@test.com
    [label[name]] => Some name
    [controllers[page][title_new]] => New page
    [controllers[page][title_edit]] => Edit page
    [controllers[page][submit_button]] => Submit page
 )
```

The following code works "fine":

```
$data = some_data;
$result = array();

foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
  if (is_array($v))
    foreach ($v as $_k => $_v)
      if (is_array($_v))
        foreach ($_v as $__k => $__v)
          if (is_array($__v))
            foreach ($__v as $___k => $___v)
              $result[$k.'['.$_k.']['.$__k.']['.$___k.']'] = $___v;
          else
            $result[$k.'['.$_k.']['.$__k.']'] = $__v;
      else
        $result[$k.'['.$_k.']'] = $_v;
  else
    $result[$k] = $v;
}
```

The code work nicely for four levels, and after that it returns "Array" as the value. I think I need recursion, but I would like for you to review my current code, and optionally present me with a solution to go even deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I probably need some kind of recursion, but I have no clue how to get around that with PHP

Recursion in PHP is the same as basically any language (well... at a very high level).

I'm very torn on if I think your question is on topic or not, but it's been a long time since I've written anything recursive, and I'm a shameless rep-whore, so here's my go:

```
function flatten(array $arr, $prefix = '')
{
    $out = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $key = (!strlen($prefix)) ? $k : "{$prefix}[{$k}]";
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $out += flatten($v, $key);
        } else {
            $out[$key] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Or, if you don't like the magical second param:

```
function _flatten(array &$out, array $arr, $prefix)
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $key = (!strlen($prefix)) ? $k : "{$prefix}[{$k}]";
        if (is_array($v)) {
            _flatten($out, $v, $key);
        } else {
            $out[$key] = $v;
        }
    }
}

function flatten(array $arr)
{

    $flat = array();
    _flatten($flat, $arr, '');
    return $flat;

}
```

You could also optimize a bit and make a lot of the things in there references (the for loop values and function params).  I tend to avoid references in PHP though unless I have an extremely strong reason for them.  (If you plan on using this function on arrays larger than a few hundred elements, that may begin to enter into strong reason land.)

(And `flatten` is a horrible name, but... yeah.)

Comment: Hey, that works pretty great. Usually the arrays are indeed bigger than a few hundred elements, but not like thousands. I will try to get some benchmarks on them. Thanks!

Comment: Well very simple tests do show that $key = $prefix ? $k : "{$prefix}[{$k}]"; is a lot faster then the !strlen() check. Why do you use that? Other than that it looks fast enough to me.

Comment: @Tessmore Because `0` is a valid key and considered false.  I suppose a faster version than strlen could be `((string) $prefix) !== '')`.  Or, the fastest would probably actually be to have $prefix default to null and just check `$prefix === null`.

Comment: Ye I did the last one